# hide column in gridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i had a dataset that return the following data CategoryDI, CategoryName, CateoryPicture im displaying these data using gridview however i want to display only CategoryName hide categoryid, and CategoryPicture im uinsg the following code but it not working please help me thank you

GridView1.DataSource = getDataSet.Tables(0)

```
    GridView1.DataBind()

    GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
    GridView1.Columns(1).Visible = true
    GridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 protected void gvDocuments_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: This way is a much more organized and separated way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

```
  Me.GridView1.DataSource = ds6
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    If GridView1.Columns.Count > 0 Then
        Me.GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
        Me.GridView1.Columns(9).Visible = False
        Me.GridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
        Me.GridView1.Columns(3).Visible = False 
    Else
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Visible = False
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(9).Visible = False
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Visible = False
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Visible = False
        For Each gvr In GridView1.Rows
            gvr.Cells(0).Visible = False
            gvr.Cells(9).Visible = False
            gvr.Cells(2).Visible = False
            gvr.Cells(3).Visible = False
        Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

in your aspx page, make sure you're defining your gridview with 'AutogenerateColumns=False' and then specify the columns you want to see.

for instance :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
 GridLines="Horizontal" Width="800px" ShowFooter="False" CssClass="grid"  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
    <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="CategoryName"></asp:BoundField>
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Picture" DataField="CategoryPciture"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
  <asp:GridView>
```

That will show only the columns you want to see.

in your codebebind, just do a

```
 mygrid.Datasource= xxx
```

followed by a

```
 mygrid.databind
```

that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
.DisplayNone
{
 Display:none   
}
```

Then place the following before the end 'BoundField' tag for each of the columns that you want make invisible:

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="DisplayNone"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle CssClass="DisplayNone"></ItemStyle>
```

appear just as if you had specified 'Visible=False" but it will be accessible to your code. Bear in mind however that it will appear if you 'view source' from the browser, so don't use this technique if the hidden data is sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

a simple example of code

```
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns("CategoryID").Visible = False
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns("CategoryName").Visible = False
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns("CateoryPicture").Visible = False
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

but it gave me the following

```
Conversion from string "Branch" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    setMenu()
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    lbldte.Text = DateAndTime.Now.ToShortDateString
    If Page.PreviousPage IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim GridView1 As GridView = DirectCast(Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView)

    End If
    If Session("ProductsTable") IsNot Nothing Then
        dt = DirectCast(Session("ProductsTable"), DataTable)

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
        If GridView1.Columns.Count > 0 Then
            Me.GridView1.Columns("Branch").Visible = False
            Me.GridView1.Columns("Visit date").Visible = False
            Me.GridView1.Columns("Emp.Age").Visible = False
        End If
    End If

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'check if the webpage is loaded for the first time.
        'Saves the Previous page url in ViewState
        ViewState("PreviousPage") = Request.UrlReferrer
    End If
End Sub
```